# Property [img_pers] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just get an error in my blade it call

Property [img_pers] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AppGestion\resources\views\frontend\etat_civil.blade.php)

my controller code :

```
 public function index()
   {
     $listpers = Personne::all();
     return view('frontend.etat_list', ['personnes' => $listpers]);
   }
```

code view :

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/avatars/'.$personnes->img_pers) }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="height:300;" />
```

fonction store :

```
 public function insert(Request $request)
    {

      $image = time().'.'.$request->file('img_pers')->extension();
      $path = $request->file('img_pers')->storeAs('avatars',$image);


      $pers = new Personne();

      $pers->img_pers = $image;

       $pers->save();

      return redirect('etat_lists');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning all the persons. They come in as a collection array. You provide that array to your view, but you than try to access a property on the array. That's not possible, you need to first get one of the items in the array, than access the property:

```
$personnes->first()->img_pres
```

Have a look at the `Collections` documents for more info on collections.

Comment: but they get the first image for all users , i want each user by their own champ

Comment: Then wrap the `<IMG>` line in a `foreach` loop. The point is you are sending an array to the view and you need to first access an array item, which is the `Personne` object, from which you can than access the `img_pres`.